# how to authorise OAuth2 in tvOS

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, swift3, tvos, tvos10

app going to unknown state and doesn't do anything i'm having this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for P2Auth2 and can't authorise

```
    Authenticator.sharedInstance.oauth2 = OAuth2
    Authenticator.sharedInstance.reauthorizeSilently(callback: { (wasFailure, error) -> Void in
                if (!wasFailure) {
                    print("Re-Auth Successfull")

                } else {
                    print("Re-Auth failed")
                }
            })
    return true
```

Answer (score 1):

As tvOS does not support web views, it seems unlikely that you will be able to directly log in from AppleTV. Most AppleTV solutions that succeed use a second device to acquire the OAuth login token. If you can authenticate directly without using OAuth2, I recommend that you do so.